# Providing inputs to an interactive bash script's while loop from python

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to run a bash script using python and want to store the output of the terminal into an output.txt file.

My bash script name is exe.bash

```
#G
G()
{
chmod 0755 some_binary
sudo ./some_binary
}

#Execution starts from here

echo "----------------------------------------"
echo Please select a number
echo 1. something 
echo 2. something 
echo 3. something
echo 4. something
echo 5. something
echo 6. something
echo 7. something

read input
#Select input
    case $input in
    1 ) A ;;
    2 ) B ;;
    3 ) C ;;
    4 ) D ;;    
    5 ) E ;;
    6 ) F ;;
    7 ) G ;;
    * ) echo "invalid input" ;;
    esac
#Done
```

My python script name is callexe.py

```
import subprocess
with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
    subprocess.call(["./exe.bash", "7", "3"], stdout = output, shell = True)
```

For the interactive bash script, the first input is 7 which takes us to an infinite while loop. And from then it should be given 3 as its input.

What I have done just fails because it provides only 2 arguments. Can someone help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: What error do you get, also it would help if you posted a redux version of your `exe.bash` script.

Comment: Pressing 7 starts executing some binary and I have to keep on entering 3 in every 30 second time interval @zwer

Comment: Well your script doesn't expect any arguments - it expects passing the data via STDIN.

Comment: If you need to interact with another process (a shell script in this case), you might want to look into pexpect.

Comment: There is no _while loop_ in the posted code, so it is incomplete.